# Error in adding icons to subitems in listview

Tags: vb.net

I want to add a icon in one of the columns of my listview, but I keep getting the same error. I have the listview in details but I can only add an icon in the first column.

Code:

```
Dim linha As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(txtNumero.Text, 0)

linha.SubItems.Add(txtNome.Text)
linha.SubItems.Add(txtIdade.Text)
linha.SubItems.Add(txtEquipa.Text)

linha.SubItems.Add(cbxCapacete.SelectedItem, 0)
```

The last one that I try to add gienter code hereves, I get this error:

> Error BC30516
>   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' accepts this number of arguments.

But in this case

```
Dim linha As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(txtNumero.Text, 0)
```

works fine.

Comment: ***SubItems*** does not support Images or Icons in normal mode 
But this is not the end ,You can draw anything inside `Items` or `subItems` if you change `OnwerDraw = True` then draw each area using `linha_DrawSubItem`